# Really disabling hibernation in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, hibernate

I am aware of several guides detailing how to disable hibernation essentially setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power` key `HiberbootEnabled` to zero (either directly or via GUI).

Unfortunately this seems *not* to be enough with current Win10.

Reason why I need this (and I know it does not work) is I need to have a dual-boot system Linux (mostly) and win10 (for gaming only).

GRUB will refuse to install (win launcher) if partition is "unclean" (i.e.: shutdown was not complete because of hibernation and partition was not correstly unmounted).

Intense and long disk activity at shutdown is consistent with writing memory yo hiberfil.

How can I convince Win10 to really **DIE** when I turn it off?

**Update**: as requested here's what Linux complains about, in spite of the above Registry setting.

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb4 /mnt
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
mcon@cinderella:~$ ls -la /mnt
total 18644708
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4096 Nov 25 00:18  .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root        4096 Dec  4 14:49  ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root           0 Nov 10 22:22 '$Recycle.Bin'
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root           0 Nov 14 22:03  AMD
lrwxrwxrwx  2 root root          10 Nov 10 19:50 'Documents and Settings' -> /mnt/Users
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 13723422720 Dec 12 22:18  hiberfil.sys
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  5100273664 Dec 12 19:55  pagefile.sys
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root           0 Nov 11 10:42  PerfLogs
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4096 Nov 11 11:11  ProgramData
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root        8192 Nov 18 21:31 'Program Files'
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4096 Nov 30 22:22 'Program Files (x86)'
lrwxrwxrwx  2 root root          18 Nov 10 19:50  Programmi -> '/mnt/Program Files'
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root           0 Nov 11 10:48  Recovery
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   268435456 Dec 12 19:55  swapfile.sys
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4096 Dec  9 00:11 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root        4096 Nov 11 10:54  Users
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16384 Dec 11 21:01  Windows
```

As You can see `hiberfil.sys` is alive and kicking with dates consistent with yesterday usage.

Comment: I have several Windows 10 Pro machines here and they all shut down cleanly and properly. Hibernation has been turned OFF on all of them. If that is not working, perhaps look at the Grub setup or see if your machine has a strange BIOS setup. I know the Windows part and my own BIOS setup but not yours or Grub.

Comment: @John: this has nothing to do with GRUB (currently, I might have problems with it later though) Linux itself refuses to mount windows partition stating it was not shut down cleanly (offers to mount ReadOnly) because of hybernation (I can post the exact message next time I'll reboot Linux).

Comment: Let us know about the message. Windows works just fine.

Comment: @John: Please see updated OP (I won't follow You in polemic about "works just fine").

Comment: GRUB does not mount, install to, or do anything with the Windows partition except detect it. You can dual-boot with Linux just fine whether Windows is hibernated or not.

Comment: @kreemoweet: If You are GRUB-savvy perhaps you can help me with my other GRUB-centered [problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620613/update-grub-does-not-see-my-win10-installation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just perform the following in CMD as Administrator:

```
powercfg -h off
shutdown /s /t 0
```

For that matter, to dual boot, you can make a .bat script of this and execute as Administrator. Another script with `powercfg -h on` would allow use of hiberfil.sys if you do *not* plan to boot to Linux soon.

There should be *no* reason to play with the Registry.

These *powercfg* commands are remembered even after reboot; thus one .bat script can enable/disable Hibernation *until* the converse one is run.

Comment: This works perfectly (thus I accepted answer). Is there any way to "permanently inform windows of my wishes" or should I always use the above script to shutdown? I mean: what happens if I shut system down from `start` menu?

Comment: once you run powercfg -h off, hibernation is disabled across reboots, no need to run it again.